# Finding a tool / Help with writing a matrix representation in ordered bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

For my linear algebra homework I have to find the following:

Define the linear transformation $T:P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R^3}$ by $T(a+bx+cx^2) = (a+b, c, a-b)$. Let $\beta $ and $\gamma$ be the standard bases for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Now find $[T]^\gamma_\beta$.

My final answer was $[T]^\gamma_\beta =  
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ $

Now I have no idea is this is right, but instead of having to ask a question every time I want to check an assignment, it would be nice if there was some kind of calculator or tool that can calculate this expression given the transformation and bases. Does anyone know of such a tool (and perhaps while we're at it, if this answer is even nearly correct)?

Comment: I’d be more concerned that you don’t have any idea of whether or not you got the right answer or how you might verify your solution yourself than about finding some tool to do the work for you.

Comment: I don't want the tool to do the work for me necessarily, I would just like the verification. As of now, no, I don't know how to verify my own answer. Also, the tool would be nice to play around and see what happens in different scenarios, so that way I can understand how this works in different situations.

Comment: The matrix $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ is defined by the property $[T(v)]_\gamma = [T]_\beta^\gamma [v]_\beta$ for every $v \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$.  Does your matrix satisfy this for $v = 1, x, x^2$?  If so, then it is correct.

Comment: @Quasicoherent I'm not really sure what $[T(v)]_\gamma$ and $[v]_\beta$ mean and what they look like so I'm not sure how to check my answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector